# Unable to convert BSONTimestamp to date to right date

Tags: datetime, bson

i m having trouble in converting the BSONTimeStamp to date , it is always giving me result dated 1969 , this is code i m using

```
BSONTimestamp time = doc['ts']
println "time"+ new Date(time.getTime() *1000)
```

which is

```
BSONTimestamp time = doc['ts']
println "time"+ new Date(1445947090 *1000)
```

but this is giving

```
Mon Dec 15 08:48:31 IST 1969
```

Can anybody guide me please !!

Comment: BSON is just a serialization format.  It would help if we knew what language and environment you were using.

Comment: However, the date you show is significantly before the 1970 Unix Epoch, more than could be accounted for by time zone offsets.  Therefore either the `Date` object you're using is based on some other epoch, or you passed in a negative value - not the value shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the long suffix in unix time conversion.

```
BSONTimestamp time = doc['ts']
println "time"+ new Date(time.getTime() *1000L)
```